# Modern Physics: Invariance of mass in an isolated system

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, momentum, inertial-frames

**Problem:** Suppose two photons, one with energy 5 MeV and the second with energy 2 MeV, approach each other along the $x$ axis.
What is the rest energy of this system?

**The thought track I used:**

1) Photons move at speed of light $c$.

2) Photons are massless and have zero rest energy ($mc^2=0$)

3) The formula $E^2=(mc^2)^2 +(pc)^2 $ reduces to $E=pc$

4) We have the energies now we can find the $p_1 = E_1/c$  & $p_2=E_2/c$.

5) $\sum_i p_i = p_1+p2 = 3 \ Mev/c$

6) Now since we are considering the system and not individual particle we cannot assume that the mass of the system is zero and we use   $E^2=(mc^2)^2 +(pc)^2 $ finding m we get m=6.32 MeV.

**Conclusions:**
Even though the mass of the constituents is zero the mass of the system for all inertial frames observing the **"System of the photons"** do see a non-zero value for the mass however if the observers are to see the mass of constituent particles we have to use $m=\gamma m_0$ in this case $m=0$ . In the case where we consider particles who have a mass we get both a non zero value for observed mass of system and constituents.

Are my conclusions and thought track correct?

[image]

Comment: you do not really means kg !!!. The units are in MeV . Life is  conceptually simpler if one adds four vectors and takes the "length" http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Relativ/vec4.html

Comment: The rest frame is the frame with zero total momentum.

Comment: This is rather convoluted.  The 4-magnitude of the photon energy momentum vector is zero.  They live in the Null hyper space of space-time.  That is how you get the E ~ p relation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Michele says, your method works.
As @annav says, using 4-vectors is simpler.

Elaborating on those comments,
here is an energy-momentum diagram (analogous to a spacetime diagram)
drawn on "rotated graph paper" [so that we can ***easily read off values from the diagram***].

We illustrate the sum of energy-momentum vectors
$$\tilde K_1 + \tilde K_2 = \tilde P_{com}.$$

Algebraically,
in the lab frame, $\tilde P_{com}$ has
 
components 
$E_{com}=(5)+(2)=7$ and
$p_{com}=(5)+(-2)=3$,
 and thus has magnitude
$\sqrt{ E_{com}^2- p_{com}^2}=\sqrt{ (7)^2-(3)^2}=\sqrt{40} \approx 6.3246$.

Diagrammatically, 
the "[mass] diamond" (analogous to the "causal diamond") of OP
has
 
(in this frame) width $u=10$ and height $v=4$.
It has area $uv=(10)(4)=40$
 and
aspect ratio $\frac{width}{height}=\frac{u}{v}=\frac{10}{4}$.

It turns out that the magnitude of $\tilde P_{com}$ (the rest energy) is equal to the square root of that area.
 
So, $E_{com}=|\tilde P_{com}|=\sqrt{(Area)}=\sqrt{uv}=\sqrt{(10)(4)}=\sqrt{40}$.

It also turns out that the "square of the doppler factor of the center-of-momentum frame" $k_{com}^2$ is equal to the aspect ratio.
So, the velocity of the center of momentum frame is $\beta_{com}=\frac{k_{com}^2-1}{k_{com}^2+1}=\frac{\left(\frac{10}{4}\right)-1}{\left(\frac{10}{4}\right)+1}=\frac{10-4}{10+4}=\frac{6}{14}=\frac{3}{7}.$

The components are
$E_{com}=\frac{u+v}{2}=\frac{(10)+(4)}{2}=7$
and
 
$p_{com}=\frac{u-v}{2}=\frac{(10)-(4)}{2}=3$.

[Secretly, we are using light-cone coordinates (in my conventions).]

[image: Energy momentum diagram on rotated graph paper]

(Further details are in this blog entry: https://www.physicsforums.com/insights/relativity-rotated-graph-paper/, which describes my paper: "Relativity on Rotated Graph Paper" Am. J. Phys. 84, 344 (2016); http://dx.doi.org/10.1119/1.4943251 ).
)

Answer (score 1):

Your demonstration simply states that the rest mass of a composite is made up of the rest mass of the constituents plus their kinetic energy plus the possible interaction energy between them.

If the components are massless, e.g. photons, what remains is the kinetic energy plus possible interactions.

In principle your picture is correct.